# $this function does not work after PHP update from 5x to 7.2

Tags: php, this

```
function getOrder($arr, $order, $this) {
    $type = 'asc';
    if($orderBy = $arr[$this])
        if(isset($_GET[$order])) {
            $v = explode('_', strrev($_GET[$order]), 2);
            if(strrev($v[1]) == $this)
                $type = (strrev($v[0]) == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
        }

    return $this . '_' . $type;
}
```

This error is produced:

> Cannot use $this as parameter in /var/www/config-and-functions.php on
>   line 498

Can anyone solve this problem that appeared when I migrated from to PHP 7.2 from 5x?

Comment: what is $this? class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do to fix it is rename the variable.

Using `$this` as a parameter name is disallowed now because `$this` refers to the current instance of an object when used in a method. Naming a parameter `$this` conflicts with that meaning. This sometimes caused unexpected/confusing behavior in older versions of PHP, because it wasn't obvious which `$this` you were referring to, so it's no longer allowed.

Obviously the `$this` in this function isn't referring to an object, it's a string. So just rename it in the function signature and anywhere it's used inside the function. Doesn't really matter what as far as PHP syntax, as long as it's a valid variable name, but it's better if you can use a name that gives an indication of what it actually is for.

```
function getOrder($arr, $order, $that) {
    $type = 'asc';
    if($orderBy = $arr[$that])
        if(isset($_GET[$order])) {
            $v = explode('_', strrev($_GET[$order]), 2);
            if(strrev($v[1]) == $that)
                $type = (strrev($v[0]) == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
        }

    return $that . '_' . $type;
}
```